# Are the white bits on this beef jerky fat or mold?

Tags: beef, mold, jerky

[image: photo]

I can’t tell if this is simply fat or mold. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt - throw it out

Fat shouldn't be white at room temperature. If you kept it in the fridge and put the meat in an oven at some low temp (200F for like 10 min), and the "white stuff" melts, it's probably fat

Comment: I disagree that fat shouldn't be white at room temp; every time I've had a cooled piece of cooked meat, the fats have been white.

Comment: @bob1 cooled how?

Comment: Any method, particularly obvious on pork, but also beef, chicken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is fat. I think it is sinew. I make jerky pretty often and even fresh jerky tends to have some white streaks from connective tissue; they don't really absorb the marinade and stay white. And the tiny bit of fat that melts out can also be white if you refrigerate your jerky, but that normally looks more like droplets.

That said, I can't tell how it smells or tastes over the Internet, so as stated in most questions of this nature, better safe than sorry.